# python, dumping a pandas dataframe in a sql database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, mysql

What should be the best way to dump a pandas dataframe into a sql database?
Is it better to first convert the dataframe into a csv file then dump the csv file or write into the sql database line by line?

Comment: Did you try both? If you tried, which one do you think is better or why is one of them better? Speed? maintainability?

Comment: I tried both, using a csv is much faster but i don't know in term of maintainability @user1767754

Comment: You wan't get a really response here, as stackoverflow is specialized for questions and answers, maintainability can be pipeline dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html
The fastest way is you use it with sqlAlchemy and not with the legacy DBAPI2.

Comment: That is not fully true, using a DBAPI connection will be a bit faster, but is only supported for sqlite, while working with sqlalchemy engines is supported for all databases that sqlalchemy supports.